# How to convert Html text into normal plain text?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have `html text` which is coming from `backend` and i need to convert it into normal text to show up in TextArea.

Is there any way to convert Html text into normal plain`text by using`Flex framework`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use Regexp to remove tags.

From [here](http://snipplr.com/view/28362/):

```
var myString:String = "<p><b>bold</b> <i>italic</i> <a href='#'>link</a> <br>linebreak</p>";
trace(myString)
var removeHtmlRegExp:RegExp = new RegExp("<[^<]+?>", "gi");
myString = myString.replace(removeHtmlRegExp, "");
trace(myString);

// OUTPUT
// <p><b>bold</b> <i>italic</i> <a href='#'>link</a> <br>linebreak</p>
// bold italic link linebreak
```

In case I got you wrong and you want to display HTML tags in textarea, use `escape()` function

Comment: I dont think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @loxxy explain, then, what he wants?

Comment: Exactly what you added at the end. Shouldn't it be unescape function??

Comment: No. It's clearly escape(). And judging by his upvote, original answer met his needs.